What is the centralizer $C_P(B)$ mean, where $A \times B =\operatorname{Aut}(P)$?
In the book Finite groups - Daniel Gorenstein, Theroem 5.3.4 says:

Let $A \times B$ be a group of automorphisms of a $p$-group $P$ with $A$ a $p'$-group and $B$ a $p$-group. If $A$ acts trivially on $C_P(B)$, then $A=1$.

My question is, what does $C_P(B)$ mean?
I think it mean $C_P(B) =\{ p \in P \mid pb=bp, \forall b \in B \}$.
But, what is the operation between $P$ and $B$?

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

I believe it is the centraliser of $B$ in $P$.

You haven't described what $P$ is.

This is more difficult than I thought initially.  You're asking about the operation, not what the centraliser is; and I don't know.

Maybe it view $B$ as a group action on $P$, but I'm not sure how to do it.

$B$ is a set of automorphisms of $P$. So $C_P(B)$ just means those elements of $P$ left fixed by every element in $B$.

Why $B$ is a set of automorphisms of $P$?

Umm..it's in the quote you wrote?

It only says, $A \times B$ is a automorphism group of $P$.

They intend an internal direct product.

As @SteveD said,  does $C_P(B)$ mean the set of element $P$ which left fixed by every element in $1 \times B$?(where $1$ is the identity in $A$)
